# Finding non missing value percentage of each group across DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code whenever I wish to calculate the % of non missing values in a column (say a) when groupby an id column:

```
df.groupby('id')['a'].apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum()/len(x)*100)
```

If I want to calculate for multiple columns I have to loop through. Is there a better way to avoid looping over the columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try

```
df.groupby('id')['a','b'].apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum()/len(x)*100)
```

Comment: Ahh, so instead of looping, just put in a list of columns

Comment: Yap, that should be able to do. Using the`loc` accessor, you can pull a range of columns and parse them if needed. If happy, please accept and or upvote so that other can use your question and my answer confidently.